# iOS open a page or anchor of a book (in ePub format) in Books using URL scheme

Tags: ios, swift, epub, ibooks

I would like to know whether there is a URL scheme to open an ePub in iBooks and navigate directly to a page number or anchor tag from iOS (objective-c or swift). I can navigate to iBooks. But not able to open a particular page directly. Any sample or reference will be helpful